# ANTLR - find first match for grammar within string

Tags: search, antlr, antlr4

Is there a way to use an ANTLR parser as a searcher, i.e. to find the first instance of a substring `ss` of a longer string `S` that matches a given rule `my_rule`?

Conceptually, I could accomplish this by looking for a match at position `S[i]`, incrementing `i` until I successfully retrieve a match or `S` is exhausted.

However, in practice this doesn't work very well, because prefixes in `S` might coincidentally have characters that match tokens in my grammar.  Depending on how this happens, a valid string `ss` in `S` might get recognized several times, or skipped over erratically, or there might be lots of errors printed about "token recognition error".

Is there an approach I haven't thought of, or an ANTLR feature I don't know about?

I'm using the Python bindings for ANTLR, if that matters.

**EXAMPLE**:

Given the following grammar:

```
grammar test ;

options { language=Python3; }


month returns [val]
  : JAN {$val = 1}
  | FEB {$val = 2}
  | MAR {$val = 3}
  | APR {$val = 4}
  | MAY {$val = 5}
  ;

day_number returns [val]
  : a=INT {$val = int($a.text)} ;

day returns [val]
  : day_number WS?     {$val = int($day_number.start.text)}
  ;

month_and_day returns [val]
  : month WS day             {$val = ($month.val, $day.val)}
  | day WS ('of' WS)? month  {$val = ($month.val, $day.val)}
  ;


WS : [ \n\t]+ ;  // whitespace is not ignored

JAN : 'jan' ('.' | 'uary')? ;
FEB : 'feb' ('.' | 'ruary')? ;
MAR : 'mar' ('.' | 'ch')? ;
APR : 'apr' ('.' | 'il')? ;
MAY : 'may' ;


INT
  : [1-9]
  | '0' [1-9]
  | '1' [0-9]
  | '2' [0-3]
  ;
```

and the following script to test it:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('gen')


from testParser import testParser
from testLexer import testLexer


from antlr4 import InputStream
from antlr4 import CommonTokenStream, TokenStream


def parse(text: str):
    date_input = InputStream(text.lower())
    lexer = testLexer(date_input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = testParser(stream)
    return parser.month_and_day()


for t in ['Jan 6',
          'hello Jan 6, 1984',
          'hello maybe Jan 6, 1984']:
    value = parse(t)
    print(value.val)
```

I get the following results:

```
# First input - good
(1, 6)

# Second input - errors printed to STDERR
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'h'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:2 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'o '
line 1:11 token recognition error at: ','
(1, 6)

# Third input - prints errors and throws exception
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'h'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:2 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'o '
line 1:9 token recognition error at: 'b'
line 1:10 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:12 mismatched input 'jan' expecting INT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_grammar.py", line 25, in <module>
    value = parse(t)
  File "test_grammar.py", line 19, in parse
    return parser.month_and_day()
  File "gen/testParser.py", line 305, in month_and_day
    localctx._day = self.day()
  File "gen/testParser.py", line 243, in day
    localctx.val = int((None if localctx._day_number is None else localctx._day_number.start).text)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jan'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

To use the incremental approach I outlined above, I'd need a way to suppress the `token recognition error` output and also wrap the exception in a `try` or similar.  Feels like I'd be very much going against the grain, and it would be difficult to distinguish these parsing exceptions from other things going wrong.

*(META - I could **swear** I already asked this question somewhere about 4 months ago, but I couldn't find anything on SO, or the ANTLR GitHub tracker, or the ANTLR Google Group.)*

Comment: Is the string `S` structured, or is it some bit of arbitrary text? What is the full expression of the rule `my_rule`? Hard to understand para 3 without further details.

Comment: `S` could be completely arbitrary - in my case it's text that a user can type.  I'll add an example rule when I get back to work tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Example added to question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use an ANTLR parser as a searcher, i.e. to find the
>   first instance of a substring `ss` of a longer string `S` that matches
>   a given rule `my_rule`?

The short answer is no. ANTLR does not work as a substitute/equivalent to any of the standard regex-based tools, like `sed` and `awk`.

The longer answer is yes, but with messy caveats.  ANTLR expects to parse a structured, largely unambiguous input text.  Text that is of no semantic significance can be ignored by adding the lexer rule (at lowest priority/bottom position)

```
IGNORE : . -> skip;
```

That way, anything not explicitly recognized in the lexer is ignored.

The next problem is the potential semantic overlap between 'normal' text and keywords, *e.g.* Jan (name) - Jan (month abrev).  In general, this can be handled by adding a [`BaseErrorListener`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BaseErrorListener.java) to the parser to distinguish between real and meaningless errors. What constitutes real vs meaningless can involve complex corner cases depending on the application.

Finally, the rule

```
day_number returns [val]
  : a=INT {$val = int($a.text)} ;
```

is returning an `int` value not an `INT` token, hence the error that is being reported. The rule should be

```
day_number : INT ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful.  A couple points/questions: 1) I'm not really using ANTLR as a *substitute* for sed/awk/regex, in fact it would be far easier to do this with a text-based regex if it had ANTLR's power of parsing to a return value.  It's highly desirable to have the grammar, which understands the patterns, also be the thing that puts the pieces together to a meaningful return value.

Comment: 2)  Wouldn't ignoring all unknown characters also permit them to be present in the middle of rules I've written?  E.g. if I have a rule that matches `{month} {year}` and the user enters `Jan HI THERE 2017` it would match (erroneously to my use case), right?

Comment: 3) I don't think there's a problem with the `day_number` rule, I think the problem is that it matches the `"may"` in `"maybe"` as a `month`, then expects there to be a `day_number` next; it discards `"b", "e"` because they match no known token types; discards `" "` because it's whitespace; then tries to convert the next valid token `"jan"` to an integer, and fails.

Comment: Re (2): the rules need to be tightened up and likely predicates will be needed to deal with this problem. Messy at best, perhaps impossible at worst, leading back to the 'short' answer given above. Re (3): haven't tested, but from the error message, the rule appears to have matched a `JAN` token and was looking for, *i.e.* expecting, an `INT` token next.

Comment: Actually, Re (2): your `IGNORE : . -> skip;` idea suggests a similar solution - I can add `OTHER : . ;` and *not* skip it, so that the Lexer always succeeds, and then do `parser.removeErrorListener(ConsoleErrorListener.INSTANCE)` so that the chatter is reduced.  I think this might solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've settled on, based on a variant of an idea from @grosenberg's answer, is as follows.

1) Add a fallback lexer rule to match any text that isn't already matched by existing rules.  Do *not* ignore/skip these tokens.

```
OTHER : . ;
```

2) Add a parser alternative to match either the rule of interest, or (with lower precedence) anything else:

```
month_and_day_or_null returns [val]
  : month_and_day  {$val = $month_and_day.val}
  | .              {$val = None}
  ;
```

3) In the application code, look for either a `None` or a populated value:

```
def parse(text: str):
    date_input = InputStream(text.lower())
    lexer = testLexer(date_input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = testParser(stream)
    return parser.month_and_day_or_null()

for t in ['Jan 6',
          'hello Jan 6, 1984',
          'hello maybe Jan 6, 1984']:
    for i in range(len(t)):
        value = parse(t[i:])
        if value.val:
            print(f"Position {i}: {value.val}")
            break
```

This has the desired effect at match time:

```
Position 0: (1, 6)
Position 6: (1, 6)
Position 12: (1, 6)
```